# why was my post deleted?

Tags: discussion

*I have a legitimate question where people were answering here:*

[Unable to see the actual images in the back end](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/249348/unable-to-see-the-actual-images-in-the-back-end?noredirect=1#comment351960_249348)

Why was this post deleted by Amit Bera and what can be done about it???

Comment: @Christoph Farnleitner Thanks for trying to explain it. I'm just trying to get by...not being able to add new products because the images do not work is a pretty big deal and it's right before the holidays so I don't really understand the politics of this - I've had much longer back-and-forth in other posts and it never bothered anyone... :-(

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Amit already restored it ..